# How to stay at the current page on click on statich HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I build a Portfolio from template and want to make the contact section available.
I'm use HTML form and js, but got a problem with "onclick" or "href" attribute.
on the server-side i'm using at google-sheets.
The   form sent excellent but i want to stay at the same page after it submmited.
HTML:

```
<button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="button"> Send Message </button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".main-menu").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showSection($(this).attr("href"), true);
  });
```

There is the link for the website, do you can to enter an scroll down to get better understanding:
https://vigilant-johnson-9e38c6.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1):

You should `e.preventDefault()` at the `onsubmit` event of the form instead of on the click event of a button.

Comment: $(".main-menu").on("submit", "a", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       showSection($(this).attr("href"), true);
      });

Answer (score 0):

Add that jquery code to your script

```
$('#contact').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize())
        .done(function( data ) {
            alert('the form has been sent successfully');
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        });
});
```